# Java I/O to a .txt file

Tags: java, string, file, io

I am learning Java and so far I have been able to troubleshoot my problems with the help of Google and trail and error/reading. But I am a little lost here:

I have a list of names. I have a method that takes a string as an argument and deletes that name from the list and returns the rest of the names. I created a file that holds all the names. Once the name is deleted I want it to stay deleted for the week, then at the beginning of next week I want all the names to be listed again. 
My initial thought was to use arrays but that wouldn't work since it will be washed out of memory by the end of the program execution. So I tried writing the data to a file and reading and writing it every time. Here is my current problem:

Person1,Person2, Person3....
When I remove person1, I rewrite the file to person2 and person3 only. Then if person2  is removed I rewrite the file to only person3. The problem with this is that I have to remove sequentially otherwise strings that were previously removed will be rewritten. I want to remove one string from the list when ever that string is selected without affecting the rest.

(This is my first time posting here so if there is something I am missing let me know and I will try to improve my question. I didn't post any code because I just decided to start over and the code didn't make much sense anyways.)

Comment: show us what you have done. where you have stuck. nobody will do your homework

Comment: This is not a homework. I am doing it because I choose to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from scratch you can use [serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) feature.

Create a class which has one list variable which can hold Person1,Person2, Person3....
Using serialization you can store object into file which will have list of these names.
When you again read the object(deserialize) you will have all names from which you can delete perticular and again store the object in file.

Comment: This sounds interesting and possibly a solution. I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make 2 Files, one that keeps whatever names you want to keep, and the other ones keeps the one you want to delete. So since you already have the delete function, you can write a add function that adds names to the string. So when you run the delete name function, you put the name into the delete file, then at the beginning of next week, re-add all the names from delete files into the original file.
Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. But I am stuck on the deleting part. The way I am deleting is by rewriting the file with the list of the names that don't need to be deleted so..... if we have A,B,C, and D. If I delete C the file will be rewritten into A,B, and D. But now if I A and C: when A is removed it will be rewritten into B,C, and D and when C is removed the file becomes: A,B, and  D. I want A to stay deleted once it's deleted not reappearing when other strings are deleted. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Ya i understand, i am assuming you have a list of keeping all the names, so when you deleting you just delete from the original.
Here is the solution, before you delete, lets say you use the array, read the file that was saved from previous deleting, then delete from there. 
So if you have A,B,C,D, after delete D, you have A,B,C and it saves into a file. Then next time, you read the file you will have A,B,C, then delete C which gives you A,B and saves this to the file again.